# mysql won't allow foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Many people had this problem already, but there was no fitting solution in other posts.

I have two tables, one named "sales", the other named "host_flags". I would like to have a foreign key for host_flags.sales_id to sales.id, but mysql won't let me! I have primary indexes defined in each table, so I wonder why...

The host_flags table already has a foreign key on the column host_id, but even when I tried and created the foreign key for the sales id first, it wouldn't let me.

The tables look like:

```
CREATE TABLE `sales` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastupdate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `host_flags` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `host_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastupdate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `host_id6` (`host_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `host_id6` FOREIGN KEY (`host_id`) REFERENCES `hosts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `hosts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `creation` datetime NOT NULL,
  `lastupdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32225 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I get this error message:

```
MySQL said: Can't create table 'primarydata.#sql-191_1' (errno: 150)
```

Thanks!

Charles

### SOLUTION FOUND

All ints of the primary indexes have to be either signed or unsigned - not mixed.

Comment: "MySQL won't let you"...any error message?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "mysql won't let me!"? The exact error might be helpful.

Comment: Sure, sorry - see question edit.

Comment: Can you put the entire DDL of those 3 tables please?

Comment: @MihaiStancu Yes, see question edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Typically:

I like to declare the FK constraints outside of the table definition after all tables have been constructed.

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `constr`
        FOREIGN KEY `fk_id` REFERENCES `ftbl`(`id`)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This way I can make sure the problem isn't something like the datatype of `tbl`.`fk_id` not being the same as the one of `ftbl`.`id` (including `UNSIGNED` as @Devart said). Or not having declared `ftbl`.`id` as unique. Regardless of the order of declaration of the tables.

After i do this i can integrate the constraint back into the table definition and take into account the order in which the tables need to be created to allow the constraint to be added.

### You problem:

```
-- creating the sales table
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

-- creating the host_flags table
`sales_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

-- the sales.id is declared as unsigned
-- the host_flags.sales_id is declared signed
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it, but it still says `Can't create table 'primarydata.#sql-191_1' (errno: 150)` :-(

Comment: Please post the entire DDL for all 3 tables so we can identify the problem.

Comment: You need to declare the `hosts`  table and the `sales` table before the `host_flags` table.

Comment: You should post take the constraint out of the table definition and write it as per my example. After all tables have been created. And of course update this in the question text so we can see exactly what you are currently trying.

Comment: That is what I have been trying from the start - the tables hosts and sales exist already, only _then_ I add the table host_flags

Comment: Now build the host_flags table without the constraint. And we'll work on adding the constraints separately. BTW the current code you posted makes no mention of the FK to sales.id, only of the one to hosts.id can you check to make sure it's correct?

Comment: Your column definitions are not consistent. host_flags.sales_id is a signed integer(11) while sales.id is an unsigned integer(11)

Answer (score 0):

Additonally to Recursed's answer:

There is a requirement that foreign keys contstraints' *names* must be unique in database scope. Maybe changing the name will work?

There is also [a huge thread on MySQL community forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,19755,19755#msg-19755) about the problem containing several solutions for some specific situations.

Answer (score 0):

Possible two errors:

1. Reference and referenced columns must have the same type - `int(11) unsigned`
2. Unknown referenced table `hosts`.

Comment: With the hosts it works fine... It's with the table sales that can't be referenced to. Referenced columns are all int(11) and primary.

Comment: Change column definition if there are differences.